# Looking for a reference with an extensive list of Maclaurin series

Tags: reference-request, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find a reference that includes an extensive list of Maclaurin series. While I have found a number of useful sources, including those on [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html), [Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) (p. 52), and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series), I'm looking for something else. I aim to find articles or books that provide a vast list of Maclaurin series. Such a list would include power (Taylor/Maclaurin) series of the following:

- Composites of functions, like $\ln(\sin(x))$ or even $\cos(\exp(\arctan(x)))$.
- Uncommon or lesser known functions. Often, I find documents describing only a list of common functions.
- Sequences that hold combinatorial significance.

I hope to find something that is not merely a short chapter on Maclaurin series in a book devoted to mathematical series and other identities in general, but a document that is solely or mostly devoted to Maclaurin series (examples).

Comment: Your best bet that I'm aware of is to look up the first few terms and/or the name of the function on the OEIS: http://oeis.org/

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I tried this, but didn't have much luck.

Comment: For $\,\log(\sin(x))\,$ take a look at [OEIS sequence A283301](https://oeis.org/A283301). Try harder to look to OEIS  because there are a lot of examples included in its entries.

Comment: @Somos thank you for the link. The $\log(\sin(x))$ function was just an example to illustrate the question though. I've done extensive searching on the OEIS with the sequence I've found, including queries with the SuperSeeker. There are a couple of reasons I prefer an article over the OEIS: 1) The OEIS does not always show the general term of the power series, but sometimes just the first few terms. 2) It does not always include a reference. 3) There is often little information on how the terms were derived... (cont'd)

Comment: ... 4.) On the OEIS, the different series are usually not grouped according to some obvious categorisation method, so it can be difficult to infer structures and interrelations between the different series. Please don't get me wrong -- I like the OEIS -- but I'm looking for something else in this case

Comment: I understand the limitations that you find with OEIS, but if would be a great help if you could tell us **exactly** what you are actually looking for with an example of what you would do if you had the reference available to you. In other words, I am guessing that you have an actual problem and you think the desired reference would help you solve it. What is that problem?

Comment: @Somos I have found the first few terms of a certain sequence that pertains to the determinants of a specific type of matrices, which are: 6, 0, -60, 0, 3360, 0, -544320, 0, 199584000. These terms correspond to the numerators of the terms of some Maclaurin series function, evaluated at $x=1$. I have yet to find the general form of these terms. Once I do -- that is, if I succeed -- I will try to find Maclaurin series of which the general term looks similar to the one I've found. Then, I aim to manipulate these series to make them correspond to this general term by means of the usual techniques.

Comment: If you use the sequence $a(1..)=[6,60,3360,544320,199584000,..]$ then $a(n)n/(2n+1)!=[1,1,2,6,25,..]$ which you can lookup in OEIS but you really need one more term to cut down on the hits. Do you have another term?

Comment: @Somos Interesting. That will take a bit of time, I'll be back in about 20 minutes

Comment: @Somos Something has gone wrong with my version of Octave. I will probably take much longer than that, if my previous matrices in the command history turn out to be deleted due to a program failure.

Comment: I suggest using [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/faq.html) which is better than Octave for many purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112671/discussion-between-somos-and-max-muller).